# How can I create an angular app, using "ng new", on a shared folder in Vagrant?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Running angular CLI: 1.3.2, node: 8.4.0.

Trying to create a new angular app with "ng new" but running it on a Vagrant instance, so I need to skip the "npm install" portion so that I can manually run "npm install --no-bin-links".  I'm supposed to be able to do this:

```
# ng new myapp --skip-npm
# cd myapp; npm install --no-bin-links
```

However, --skip-npm does not appear to be a valid argument.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `--skip-install`. Check out [ng new](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new)